# Nested XML to DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, dataset, xmlreader

How do I feed the following XML to a datagridview. The Dataset.ReadXML is not working here. I tried XMLReader as well but I am unable to figure out  a method through which I can feed the data in rows and columns. I tried importing the xml to excel and Excel is able to import it properly. I want something similar and then I'll remove the columns which are not required.

```
`<root type="object">
  <gstin type="string">24AB3584G1ZL</gstin>
  <fp type="string">082017</fp>
  <b2b type="array">
    <item type="object">
      <ctin type="string">24AC7232H1ZR</ctin>
      <cfs type="string">Y</cfs>
      <cname type="null"></cname>
      <inv type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">1476.75</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">59070</txval>
                <camt type="number">1476.75</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">62024</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">12-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">217/G</inum>
          <chksum type="string">fb9401722f9f9f46cfa8ddf70647ebd47a3ca1094f4c6a17e874aea79296dcb8</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">1408.38</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">56335</txval>
                <camt type="number">1408.38</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">59152</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">12-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">218/G</inum>
          <chksum type="string">d06e30bc81f3ea8f83b735104967f878119a635dd898b33e954f41d87ebacc8c</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">1393.5</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">55740</txval>
                <camt type="number">1393.5</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">58527</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">16-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">222/G</inum>
          <chksum type="string">1a5e45053bf0665455557ea3df6b0d4d170c595b646ed54d52ef561bb66bdf77</chksum>
        </item>
      </inv>
    </item>
    <item type="object">
      <ctin type="string">24AA3022L1ZJ</ctin>
      <cfs type="string">Y</cfs>
      <cname type="null"></cname>
      <inv type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">1</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <csamt type="number">0</csamt>
                <samt type="number">1240.7</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">49628</txval>
                <camt type="number">1240.7</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">52109</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">27-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">13/119</inum>
          <chksum type="string">5951d10d389e1b6d9f6b88c536b5fc5f3676b9dd15d977a3fbe741407bd3796f</chksum>
        </item>
      </inv>
    </item>
    <item type="object">
      <ctin type="string">24AI654J1ZX</ctin>
      <cfs type="string">Y</cfs>
      <cname type="null"></cname>
      <inv type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">1</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <csamt type="number">0</csamt>
                <samt type="number">1263.83</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">50553</txval>
                <camt type="number">1263.83</camt>
                <iamt type="number">0</iamt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">53080.65</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">23-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">149</inum>
          <chksum type="string">ed7e5e187ea6349faff81f7e2eb2910a87ec4df0d70f388aa1ba4b46312032ba</chksum>
        </item>
      </inv>
    </item>
    <item type="object">
      <ctin type="string">24A6274F1ZA</ctin>
      <cfs type="string">Y</cfs>
      <cname type="null"></cname>
      <inv type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">1</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <csamt type="number">0</csamt>
                <samt type="number">748.65</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">29946</txval>
                <camt type="number">748.65</camt>
                <iamt type="number">0</iamt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">31443</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">01-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">594</inum>
          <chksum type="string">c3c6c3b9651ded60d8cd58d5659aa99e5f08a50b04e261a647fdd2e55958c03c</chksum>
        </item>
      </inv>
    </item>
    <item type="object">
      <ctin type="string">24AA064Q1ZW</ctin>
      <cfs type="string">Y</cfs>
      <cname type="null"></cname>
      <inv type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">649.45</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">25978</txval>
                <camt type="number">649.45</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">27277</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">04-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">5685/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">e4809d5e25b7df166fe140851c6d74244807c8de759bfd251cf9f2f06a4fabf5</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">136.8</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">5472</txval>
                <camt type="number">136.8</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">5746</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">05-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">5721/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">1244f4d49e7a3e50f42bb9b0f87ebd961d4a7d0900c84d5d1feff9788c27b151</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">130.97</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">5239</txval>
                <camt type="number">130.97</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">5501</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">05-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">5753/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">1eb028428be75cfdc790a0de2f7a9197099166617b46e7a4c9e4a31de17b194f</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">415.8</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">16632</txval>
                <camt type="number">415.8</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">17464</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">08-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">5826/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">c174a888d8f2ba95c78354ebefcb41d75b37902daf7ca43c2f2b2e022e501dde</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">272.8</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">10912</txval>
                <camt type="number">272.8</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">11458</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">09-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">5866/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">b1fce912197d109cf4bf19f7b585bbffabe7bcd53772369ce2a2935a0d4162bc</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">429.35</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">17174</txval>
                <camt type="number">429.35</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">18033</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">21-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">6437/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">3577ce8549a7e8853eb00b0737b2f94352abbbd70f6a12946dc803d4a245895a</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">288.7</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">11548</txval>
                <camt type="number">288.7</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">12125</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">22-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">6470/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">ef6104e50fceec2e841aaccd2814e522b2c06803fddde53cf2a343e7a551eb32</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">1515.53</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">60621</txval>
                <camt type="number">1515.53</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">63652</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">26-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">6796/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">8b666418ab813d2030d882e0f18071da91d83adfbe6d7b0ac557d70aad0877ca</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">1360.13</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">54405</txval>
                <camt type="number">1360.13</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">57125</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">28-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">6897/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">c8fb4ae410a3283c5221e9203167dc1687791a87179850c51a0f15346b317541</chksum>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">342.73</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">13709</txval>
                <camt type="number">342.73</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">14394</val>
          <inv_typ type="string">R</inv_typ>
          <pos type="string">24</pos>
          <idt type="string">29-08-2017</idt>
          <rchrg type="string">N</rchrg>
          <inum type="string">6931/J</inum>
          <chksum type="string">07ff8bcde46c86e427a2fa850c58d643f2adc32182ec674091c94f2419a787dd</chksum>
        </item>
      </inv>
    </item>
  </b2b>
  <cdn type="array">
    <item type="object">
      <cfs type="string">Y</cfs>
      <ctin type="string">24A0064Q1ZW</ctin>
      <cname type="null"></cname>
      <nt type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">59.23</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">2369</txval>
                <camt type="number">59.23</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">2487</val>
          <idt type="string">26-08-2017</idt>
          <ntty type="string">C</ntty>
          <nt_num type="string">65</nt_num>
          <inum type="string">6796/J</inum>
          <rsn type="string">02-Post Sale Discount</rsn>
          <nt_dt type="string">31-08-2017</nt_dt>
          <chksum type="string">ec636db911bbcf11b1aa200c91fe72ee4850e74886530247dc7f54353b912c93</chksum>
          <p_gst type="string">N</p_gst>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
          <itms type="array">
            <item type="object">
              <num type="number">500</num>
              <itm_det type="object">
                <samt type="number">353.98</samt>
                <rt type="number">5</rt>
                <txval type="number">14159</txval>
                <camt type="number">353.98</camt>
              </itm_det>
            </item>
          </itms>
          <val type="number">14867</val>
          <idt type="string">28-08-2017</idt>
          <ntty type="string">C</ntty>
          <nt_num type="string">74/C</nt_num>
          <inum type="string">6897/J</inum>
          <rsn type="string">02-Post Sale Discount</rsn>
          <nt_dt type="string">31-08-2017</nt_dt>
          <chksum type="string">4cf679fd864f55bcc9c4eafb039deddeb6df8ed97b495f4023548946c884b39e</chksum>
          <p_gst type="string">N</p_gst>
        </item>
      </nt>
    </item>
  </cdn>
</root>`
```

Comment: DataGridView.DataSource Property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx, and the XMl to dataset http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/load-xml-file-into-a-datagridview-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: It's not a flat set of data, so you will not be able to use only one `DataGridView` to show it. You must either pre-aggregate the data in one way or another, or you must use two `DataGridView` with the Master-Details schema.

Comment: How do I do it?